# How to pass list and dictionary to thread create function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

While creating the thread in the traditional way, I want to pass the list and dictionary objects; how to do that?

for example:

```
def expectslist(**kwargs):
    list=kwargs.values     -- not working

def expectsdict(**kwargs):
    dictobject=kwargs.values -- not working

def main():
     thread1 = Thread(target =expectslist,  (args=mylist)) # mylist is list of objects
     thread2 = Thread(target =expectsdict,  (args=mydict)) # mydict is dictionary of objects (key-objects pair)
```

Comment: First of all, none of functions you declared expect lists.

Answer (score 1):

the value of `args` is a `tuple` that holds the thread func arguments.

Example:

```
def my_sum(x,y):
  return x + y

Thread(target = my_sum,args = (5,9))
```